# How to add to make Wayland output the right resolution in VMware?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, fedora, gnome

In display settings I am getting any other resolution but 1920 x 1080. I want to change it to **1920 x 1080** resolution mode. How can I add it and change the resolution? I am running **Fedora 34** as a vm in VMware.
Gnome 40 in **Arch** has the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kinda found a workaround for now:

1. First time after boot, I log in with on `xorg` and then the resolution just appears and from nowhere, and sets itself to the 1920x1080 res.
2. Log out cause the `xorg` server is teribile, super slow and whatnot.
3. Log back in on Wayland and voilla... and just take a snapshot of the VM just in case you wanna come back just instant.. the resolution remains in display settings by the way.

**EDIT**:
I have installed the official WMware tools using [this guide](https://techviewleo.com/install-vmware-tools-manjaro-arch-linux/), second method, and everything works perfectly. it was just a VMware problem. Maybe it helps anyone struggling with the same issue. Cheers!